# Cannot assign to property: 'b0' is a get-only property

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Let me preface with this, I have very little understanding of swift (was just passed this project yesterday). I'm trying to reproduce the build in `Xcode8.3.3` and `Swift 3.1`

I've fixed a few compile sources issues and some other class related errors. I ran into  a get-only property error.

```
var cloudUse : F2Type32 = 0x1;
var anyCloudUse : Bool { 
    get { 
        return (cloudUse != 0) ? true : false 
    }
}
var iCloudUse : Bool { 
    get { 
        return cloudUse.b0 
    }
    set(newValue) { 
        cloudUse.b0 = newValue //error. Cannot assign to property: 'b0' is a get-only property
    } 
}
var googleDriveUse : Bool { 
    get { 
        return cloudUse.b1 
    }
    set(newValue) {
        cloudUse.b1 = newValue //error. Same as above 
    } 
}
```

I looked at this [get-only property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44100951/cannot-assign-to-property-xxxx-is-a-get-only-property). But still can't seem to figure out what's going on.

`b0` and `b1` are defined below

```
    extension VInt {
          func maxSize() -> UIntMax { return self.asU64 }
          init(_ val : Int) { 
                  if (val > 0) {self.init(UIntMax(val)) } 
          else { 
                  self.init(UIntMax(val&0x7fffffff)) } }
          init(fromMax : UIntMax) { self.init(fromMax) }
          init<T2 : VInt>( val : T2) { self.init(fromMax : val.asMaxSize) }
          var b0 : Bool { 
              return ((self & 0x1) == 0) ? false : true}
          var b1 : Bool { 
              return ((self & 0x2) == 0) ? false : true}
```

Comment: Show F2Type32 declaration

Comment: `typedef uint32_t F2Type32;` @antonsergeev88

Comment: Looks like you need bitmasks, try something more swifty https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059485/how-to-create-bitmask-in-swift

Comment: Is this exclusive to swift 4?

Comment: if you control click on `.b0` and `.b1` and jump to their definition, where is that code defined and what does it look like?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann updated question

Comment: @DJ2 I would first read swift documentation and then ask this question due to it's stupidity, you cannot assign value to get-only variable... it's like trying to assign value to constant...

Comment: and speaking of return ```((self & 0x1) == 0) ? false : true``` instead of  ```return ((self & 0x1) == 0)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my first attempt at a fix.  The extension currently only has a getter, so we'll edit that extension to replace the lines to something like this:

```
var b0 : Bool {
    get {return ((self & 0x1) == 0) ? false : true}
    set {self = newValue ? self & 0x1 : self ^ 0x1}
}

var b1 : Bool {
    get {return ((self & 0x2) == 0) ? false : true}
    set {self = newValue ? self | 0x2 : self ^ 0x2}
}
```

Hopefully I got the bitset stuff right (it's not my strong suit).